# 10 digest iterations reached in angularjs when using $state.go

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using angular with ionic.

I do not want the user to have to login again in case he is already logged in and did not logout the last time he used the application. For the reason, I am using local storage to check if the user is logged in.
I tried putting this code in run block.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    if($localStorage.userInfo){
        $state.go('Deployment');   //This is line 270 of app.js
         event.preventDefault();
                return;

        }
      })
```

but it gives an error that says:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Scope.$broadcast (ionic.bundle.js:23414)
    at Object.transitionTo (ionic.bundle.js:40804)
    at Object.go (ionic.bundle.js:40671)
    at app.js:270
    at Scope.$broadcast (ionic.bundle.js:23412)
    at Object.transitionTo (ionic.bundle.js:40804)
    at Object.go (ionic.bundle.js:40671)
    at app.js:270
    at Scope.$broadcast (ionic.bundle.js:23412)
    at Object.transitionTo (ionic.bundle.js:40804)
```

Also,

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
    at ionic.bundle.js:8755
    at Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:22973)
    at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:23198)
    at done (ionic.bundle.js:18351)
    at completeRequest (ionic.bundle.js:18541)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (ionic.bundle.js:18482)
```

How do I fix these errors?

config in my app looks like this:

```
.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
  $stateProvider
  .state('Login',{
    url:'/login',
    templateUrl:'templates/login.html',
    controller:'LoginCtrl'
  })

  .state('Deployment',{
    url:'/deployment',
    templateUrl:'templates/deployment.html'
  })
  .state('Bill',{
    url:'/bills',
    templateUrl:'templates/bills.html'
  })
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
})
```

**Edit 1:**
After reading [this github link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1022)

I changed my if condition to

```
 if($localStorage.userInfo != null && toState.name != 'Deployment'){
            $state.go('Deployment');
             event.preventDefault();
                    return;

            }
```

and `Maximum call stack size exceeded went away`.

But I am still left with `10 digest iterations reached`.

**Edit:2**

I changed

```
`$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');` in app.js
```

to

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector) {
           var $state = $injector.get('$state');
            $state.go('Login');
        });
```

after which I am pretty sure that I have missed some condition in if statement i.e

```
   if($localStorage.userInfo != null && toState.name != 'Deployment')
```

Can I please get some help with what I might have missed that was leading to the infinite loop ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation of the `ui-router` http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state the `$stateChangeStart` event can be cancelled with `event.preventDefault()` however you are initiating a transition before you cancel the old one.

Hence since `toState.name` isn't a documented property it seems that this will fail again and again on the condition and keep spawning new state changes.

Try:

```
if($localStorage.userInfo != null && toState.$current.name != 'Deployment'){
    event.preventDefault();
    $state.go('Deployment');
    return;
}
```

Comment: @SimranKaur are you able to post a jsfiddle perhaps?